# Execute chrome extension function before opening a connection to the site?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first time ever touching any sort of client sided web programming language, and, I'm attempting to make my first chrome addon. Basically what I want to do is code something which redirects from:-

ABC.com/ID

to

A.ABC.com/ID

So far I have it all coded, however, what it does is it loads ABC.com/ID, waits for it to complete, then injects my content script and re-loads A.ABC.com/ID. This is obviously a huge waste of time. Is there any way I can tell chrome to load this script either before the DNS lookup (Because that's useless, because it's on a new subdomain), or, before opening a connection to the site (Because this isn't the page we're looking for)? I understand a content script may not be the best idea, if it's not, then what would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve with [**web request API**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) without any content scripts. The following demonstration blocks all [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) URL's and redirects them to [`Google`](http://www.google.co.in/), similarly use `ABC.com/ID` instead of [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) and use `A.ABC.com/ID` instead of [`Google`](http://www.google.co.in/) for this use case.

### References

- [**Web request**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)
- [**Background Page**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- **[Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)**

#### `manifest.json`

Ensure all permissions are available and register background page with extension.

```
{
  "name": "Hanlder for Navigation",
  "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050467",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions":["https://www.facebook.com/*","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"]
}
```

#### `background.js`

This code blocks all URL request to [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) and redirects them to [`Google`](https://www.facebook.com/).

```
// Register an event listener which 
//traces all requests before being fired
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    return {
        redirectUrl: "http://www.google.co.in/" /*Redirection URL*/
    };
}, {
    urls: ["*://www.facebook.com/*"] /* List of URL's */
}, ["blocking"]); // Block intercepted requests until this handler has finished
```

### `Output`

All request(s) to [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) are redirected to [`Google`](https://www.google.co.in/).